# How to use a plain XML file in angular

Tags: angular, xml

I need some xml in my angular app. The simplest way would be to put it into a string, like:

```
xml = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>\n' +
  '<note>\n' +
  '  <to>Tove</to>\n' +
  '  <from>Jani</from>\n' +
  '  <heading>Reminder</heading>\n' +
  '  <body>Don\'t forget me this weekend!</body>\n' +
  '</note>';
```

but that's ugly and my IDE does not help me with the syntax. I would like to put it in an extra file, e.g. in assets. But I don't want to use a complex mechanism to GET it on runtime and to bother if it is loaded correctly. I want something like the template mechanism of a component with **xmlfile**, so it gets packed with webpack and is included with the other sources:

```
@Component ({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
  xmlfile: './some.xml' // THAT DOES NOT WORK ACTUALLY
})
```

Is there no elegant way in angular?

One possibility would be to include it in index.html and reference it with id, but that ist suboptimal:

```
<script id="myxml" type="application/xml">
  <note>
    <to>Tove</to>
    <from>Jani</from>
    <heading>Reminder</heading>
    <body>Don't forget me this weekend!</body>
  </note>
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably not as much help with this problem as you'd like (since it doesn't help with XML syntax checking), but if you quote your XML with backticks, like a template string, it will look a lot nicer than your first example using single quotes and concatenation.

```js
xml = `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <note>
    <to>Tove</to>
    <from>Jani</from>
    <heading>Reminder</heading>
    <body>Don\'t forget me this weekend!</body>
  </note>`;
```